# Ошибка в сообщении о тех.обслуживании сайта

Tags: дефект, локализация

Случайно обновление страницы попало на техническое обслуживание:

[image: тся-ться]

слишком мягкое пояснение, надо бы тверже, без мягкого знака :)

Comment: Тоже глаз резануло.

Comment: Или добавить «может». Обслуживание может длиться)

Comment: @vp_arth с "Обычно" тогда не будет стыковаться.

Comment: Согласен, полная копия. Правда, комментарии к исходному вопросу (да и давность его) не сильно обнадеживают.

Comment: Тех.обслуживание не часто бывает, поэтому и приоритет такой низкий для этой проблемы. Ну и расположение этих строк тоже имеет значение, будь они как все остальные строки, их можно было бы перевести средствами (бесплатных) участников, а так нужны сотрудники компании (которые з/п получают).